# Express.io does not load Javascript file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, coffeescript, pug

I have a Express.io server running, which works fine, however my Javascript files will not load properly.

I have a Jade file, which looks like this:

```
html
    head
        h1 Test index
    body
        script(src="/socket.io/socket.io.js")
        script(src="/javascripts/inHTML.js")
```

and a Coffescript file which looks like this:

```
express = require('express.io')
app = express()
r   = require('rethinkdb')

app.get '/', (req, res) ->
    res.render '../../client.jade'
```

The Jade file does load and `script(src="/socket.io/socket.io.js")` loads properly as well, however the second `<script>` tag returns an `GET` error when I am inspecting the site with Chrome. I have tried multiple paths to make it work, unfortunately without success. I do not see any reason why `script(src="/socket.io/socket.io.js")` does load, while my other `script` does not.

My project looks like this: website is the main directory, which contains

- coffeescripts (folder)
- javascripts (folder - has app.js and inHTML.js)
- data (folder)
- node_modules (folder - has /socket.io/socket.io.js)
- Package.json (file)
- client.jade (file)

When I `console.log __dirname` is prints `website/javascripts`

I also tried `app.use express.static('../' + __dirname)` or anything similar, also no success.

EDIT:
I tried to do the [Express.io Routing Example](https://github.com/techpines/express.io/tree/master/examples/routing), however I want the Javascript in a seperate `.js` file.

Comment: There is too much information missing to debug your case. How come `/socket.io` is properly mapped while `/javascripts` is not? What further routes and middleware has been defined? Check the sorting of your routing/middleware definitions for some unintended route might match `/javascripts` prior to the one you want to match.

Comment: 1. How are you serving your files now? (Are you using express.static?)
2. Where is socket.io located?
3. The proper way to do this (easily) is to use express.static for a folder "public" and inside that, put everything you want to serve; For example javascripts

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I am completely clueless on why `/socket.io/socket.io.js/` is working. I will edit my question with more information.

Comment: @Stian Right now I am not using express.static, but even when I do it does not seem to make a difference. socket.io is located in node_modules.

Comment: never mind socket.io, I think it servers the file itself. Could you explain what you tried with express.static a bit more clearly? Using express.static is the answer to your problem, so it is probably the way to used it that is the problem :)

Comment: @Stian I tried it in Coffeescript as well as Javascript:
`app.use express.static(__dirname + '/website')`
`app.use express.static(__dirname + '/javascripts)`

When I `console.log __dirname` it gives me the Javascript folder, which is why I also tried:
`app.use express('../' + __dirname)`

I thought that maybe it was with Coffeescript, so I edited te Javascript directly with the same code (only made it Javascript instead of Coffeescript) but with the same results.

Answer (score 0):

If i am understanding you correctly you have the javascript inHTML.js in the same directory as your executing script app.js.
`__dirname` is the name of the directory that the currently executing script resides in. That is why the console logs `website/javascripts` when you log `__dirname`.

So basically, that would mean you would write `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/'))` and `script(src="inHTML.js")`. Or maybe you could write `app.use(express.static('../'));` and `script(src="javascripts/inHTML.js")`

The most logical thing to do, and what I would suggest, is on the other hand placing your executing script, again I am assuming that is app.js, in the root directory and placing all the files you want to serve as static in the same subfolder. That way you can state that `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/nameOfSubfolder'));`. and the path to your static files will be more logical since they all have the same starting point.